# How to play audioclips in unity from script?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-source, audioclip

So I am trying to get the sing method to play one of the audioclips I created up top. I know I need an audioSource, I just have no clue how it fits in with the audioClips. I don't currently have an audiosoure assigned to the object that this script is assigned to, so that might impact things. Thanks for your help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Piano : MonoBehaviour {
private List<AudioClip> notes = new List<AudioClip>();

public string voice; 

public AudioClip ash1, a1, b1, csh1, c1, dsh1, d1, e1, f1, fsh1, g1, gsh1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //octave1
    notes.Add(a1); notes.Add(b1); notes.Add(ash1); notes.Add(c1); notes.Add(csh1);notes.Add(d1); notes.Add(dsh1);
    notes.Add(e1); notes.Add(f1); notes.Add(g1); notes.Add(gsh1);

    WarmUp(voice);
}
//consider adding countertenor, true alto (i am using mezzo soprano), and baritone.
void WarmUp(string vp)
{
    //high and low end of voice parts 
    // 30 = c4 for example
    int high;
    int low;

    ArrayList range = new ArrayList();
    //c4 to c6 
    if (vp == "Soprano")
    {
        high = 0; //this is just a range to make the code shorter
        low = 7;

        for(int i = low; i < high; i++)
        {
            range.Add(notes[i]);
        }

        Sing(range);
    }
}

/**
 * @Param: range. the arraylist of range of notes. 
 * shift the pitch UP one half step if the up arrow key is pressed
 * shift the pitch down one half step if the down arrow key is pressed
 * shift the pitch up a third (4 half steps) if the left arrow key is pressed
 * shift the pitch up a fifth (7 half steps) if the right arrow key is pressed
 */
void Sing(ArrayList range)
{
    //how to play one of the audioclips in range here
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html or maybe https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html, but, like TopRamen said, you are going to need an AudioSource for that. Then simply create a variable of type AudioSource, use GetComponent to fill that variable and simply call variableName.PlayOneShot () or variableName.Play ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach a `AudioSource` component to your GameObject.

In `Sing`:

```
yourAudioSource.clip = (AudioClip)range[Random.Range(0, range.Count)];
yourAudioSource.Play()
```

You might also consider changing  `ArrayList range` to `List<AudioClip> range` or similar to avoid the cast

Answer (score 3):

If you attach an `AudioSource` component to the `GameObject`, then you could set an `AudioSource` variable to that component and then call the setter function `clip(AudioClip x)` to set the clip the source should play. At that point, you could just call `Play()` and wait for the length of the audio clip.

Code shouldn't be too difficult to figure out but if you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable of AudioSource _aSource   and AudioClip _aClip and assign the audio source game object to the _aSource and clip to the _aClip on the inspector and where want to play the sound just write _aSource.PlayOneShot(a_Clip) that it.